Horror movie where a mother takes her daughter to the town she was adopted from
I'm remembering a movie where a mother takes her daughter to the town she (the child) was adopted from, but she only finds a glorified horror show. Pieces are missing from my memory because I saw it so many years ago but there was a church they ended up going to and the entire town was inside (as ghosts I think) as well as the girls biological mother and sister. I believe that in the end the mother and daughter leave the town and return home, but aren't in the correct reality because it shows the father in the house, then the mother and daughter in a ghostly version of the house. Please help?

Hi Selena. Please try to include as many extra details as possible in ID questions (the possible year\decade of release and the country\language, at the very least). They flesh out the question and help us narrow things down. You can find more pointers in the last section here.

Silent Hill
From Wikipedia :

The film follows Rose, who takes her adopted daughter Sharon to the town of Silent Hill, for which Sharon cries while sleepwalking. Arriving at Silent Hill, Rose is involved in a car accident and awakens to find Sharon missing; while searching for her daughter, she fights a local cult while uncovering Sharon's connection to the town's past.

Here are a few parts that match your describtion


In the church, Rose and Cybil discover a cult headed by a woman named Christabella
Christabella also sees the photo of Sharon in Rose's locket and, seeing the likeness between Sharon and Alessa.
Christopher returns home and falls asleep on the couch. He wakes up just as Rose and Sharon/Alessa return home, but they arrive in the foggy, Silent Hill version of the home, while Christopher sees rain and sunshine, indicating that Rose and Sharon/Alessa are still in an alternate reality.






I am sure, this is it.

It's my favourite movie , one of the best. Coal fire still burning deep down underground
